# C# - Downloading file from website then loading it into a control

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a DataGridView and an XML file that includes the data of the dataGridView. Basically, I have this code that I have found:

```
public static string DownloadString(string address) 
{
    string text;
    using (var client = new WebClient()) 
    {
        text = client.DownloadString(address);
    }
    return text;
}

private static void Main(string[] args) 
{    
    var xml = DownloadString(@"http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/fetchObjectAttachment.action?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002244&representation=XML");            
    File.WriteAllText("C:\Moderator\Desktop\blah.xml", xml);
}
```

However, I need to know how to make a website that downloads as soon as loaded. Also, I need to load this file as soon as it's downloaded into a dataGridView. How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to know how to make a website that downloads as soon loaded"?

Comment: Go onto the website that is in the code, and it starts downloading an XML file on load. How do you even do that?

Comment: Quite possibly via Javascript...

Comment: Any JavaScript code to do so?